# Nautilus opening from terminal but not upon clicking

Tags: command-line, 20.04, nautilus, files, nautilus-actions

I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Whenever I am clicking on the 'Files' icon in the Unity launcher or from the ubuntu dock, a buffering icon appears but Files-Manager (Nautilus) never gets launched.
However, when I type  `nautilus`  in the terminal and press enter, after quite a long time (almost 8-10 minutes) Nautilus gets launched but as soon as I close the terminal, Nautilus automatically gets closed.
I have tried almost every instruction I found on **google** and **ask-ubuntu** but none did solve my issue.
What should I do in order **to **launch** Nautilus directly just by clicking on the 'Files' icon** in Unity launcher or Ubuntu dock?

EDIT: While running Nautilus using CLI although it was launched, I got an error message which I am pasting below -->

```
(org.gnome.Nautilus:4940): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:12:35.954: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1:8: Expected a valid selector

(org.gnome.Nautilus:4940): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:12:36.012: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:11:2: Expected a valid selector
```

Comment: ...as soon as I close the terminal, Nautilus automatically gets closed...this is expected behavior. However waiting 8 to 10 minutes for nautilus to start is not. Are there any messages when run from the terminal?

Comment: Try to open Nautilus and then enter in the terminal  “journalctl -b0 -p 3” (no quotes). This may reveal errors that you need to fix. Add them to your question for help.

Comment: To see whether it is a system issue, or only a user configuration issue, temporary create a new account and see if the issue persists there. Add the outcome of your investigation to the question (use "edit")

Comment: Do you have network shares as bookmarks or 50,000+ files in your home directory?

Comment: Sounds like your issue is with your users configuration. I don’t know what this is likely to be but since they raised the question I guess @vanadium does. You can always open another terminal if the first one is busy. However in this case Ctrl-c doesn’t matter. Since you tried to open it any error message created should be visible with the journalctl command

Comment: Use the @ symbol followed by the user name you are replying to so that they will be notified that you have replied. Otherwise they may not see your reply

Comment: The warnings you’ve posted seem to be mismatches in theme versions according to other questions and answers. Have you run “sudo apt update” and “sudo apt upgrade” recently? Alternatively try a different theme.